# Fasm assembly - printf a qword variable

Tags: assembly, printf, fasm

Simple question. I've got a variable called num1:
 `num1: TIMES 4 dw 0`
i insert some hex values in(6 Byte length):
`cinvoke scanf, <"%x">, num1`.

Now, all I need is to printf it out. Sounds simple, right?

`cinvoke printf, txt, qword [num1]`

Well, it doesn't work.

What should I put instead of qword in there to make it work?

Also, is there any **real** material place for fasm assembly? I'm absolutely staggered by how little of this stuff is out there in the internet.

Comment: I don't understand your `scanf` call.  `%x` converts an `unsigned int`, which is 4 bytes.  You say 6, you actually allocated 8, and you seem to be expecting `num1` to contain a qword worth of data, which it will not.  Maybe you should clarify the types and data sizes of everything in sight here.

Comment: Is it possible you meant to use `%lx` with `scanf`?  Then assuming we are on a system with 64-bit `unsigned long`, you really will read a full 64-bit qword integer.  (Windows with its LLP64 model would need `%llx` instead, to convert `unsigned long long`.)

Comment: "doesn't work" how, specifically?  Do you mean it prints a value you weren't expecting, or crashes, or doesn't assemble, or what?  Show a [mcve] with actual vs. expected outputs.

Comment: Simply doesn't compile. Scanf works just fine, I have an issue with printf.

Comment: doesn't recognize the word "qword"

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what exactly you want to accomplish. I'm going to assume that what you want to do is to read a hexadecimal 64-bit number and then print that number in hexadecimal format, on *32-bit* x86 Windows.

You can't directly read 64 bits (one qword) from a memory address (`num1`) on a 32-bit platform. Hence, you have to read it as two 32-bit numbers (dwords) first and pass these as separate arguments:

```
format PE console
include 'win32a.inc'

section '.data' data readable writable
num1 rq 1
fmt  db "%llx"

section '.code' code readable executable
entry main
proc main
  cinvoke scanf, fmt, num1
  cinvoke printf, fmt, dword [num1], dword [num1+4]
  xor eax,eax
  ret
endp

section '.idata' data import readable
library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import  msvcrt,\
        scanf,'scanf',\
        printf,'printf'
```

> Also, is there any real material place for fasm assembly? I'm absolutely staggered by how little of this stuff is out there in the internet.

Yeah it's a pity, but there is some stuff out there. You can find the official docs [here](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual), and [here](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32) for Windows-specific macros (e.g. `win32a.inc`). Besides that, the official [forum](https://board.flatassembler.net/) can be very useful, and is reasonably active.